# Flash video player application when playing video only audio works

Tags: actionscript-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i have built my own flash video player with AS3 and it works fine but if i integrate it with rails application it plays only audio but doesn't display any thing .. anyone knows what is the problem here ?

Comment: We literally have no idea. :)

Comment: I think you need more desribe problem, how you integrate app? Post some code :)